# What is the ADL field in IMAP parsed addresses?

Tags: php, email, imap, mime

When parsing email messages [with](http://php.net/imap_headerinfo) PHP's [IMAP](http://www.php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist) extension there is a response object for each address with the following format.

```
Returns an array of objects. The objects properties are:

* mailbox - the mailbox name (username)
* host - the host name
* personal - the personal name
* adl - at domain source route
```

However, I can't seem to find any examples of what the **ADL** actually is or when it is used.

Comment: It's an obsolete "at-domain-list". It must be accepted but no longer used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's an obsolete "at-domain-list". It must be accepted but no longer used. - @mkaatman

Comment: Interesting.  I can't seem to find much on the web describing the intended usage of this at domain list.  Do you have any sources?